# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 [Eclipse, g++]

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, ld, typename

I am trying to implement my own Doubly Linked List in C++ (yes, I know std already has one) and I keep getting the famous evil compiler error:

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

I know this is common, and I have had it happen many times before and resolved it, however I cannot seem to figure out why it is happening this time around. I have seen almost every SO thread on the topic, and none of them seem to correct it.

I am using a class template, however all of my member functions are inline within the header file, and all declared functions are implemented. I am using The latest Eclipse on a Retina Macbook pro, compiling with clang.

Please help!!!

```
/*
 * StackDLL.h
 */
#ifndef STACKDLL_H_
#define STACKDLL_H_
#include <iostream>


namespace std {

template <typename T>
class StackDLL {
        /* Node in the DLL */
        struct Node {
                T data; // data held in node
                Node* next;
                Node* prev;
                Node(T data);
                Node(T data, Node* n, Node* p); // constructor

                T getData(); // gets data
                Node* getNext(); // gets node's next member
                Node* getPrev(); // gets previous member
                void setData(T data);
        }; // struct Node

    private:
        Node* head; // pointer to head of DLL
        Node* tail; // pointer to tail of DLL
        int size; // size of list

    public:
        StackDLL() {
            this->head = NULL;
            this->tail = NULL;
            this->size = 0;;
        }
        ~StackDLL() {
            while (head) {
                Node* temp(head);
                head=head->next;
                delete temp;
            }
        }


        void add(T data); // adds new node to DLL holding data of type T
        void remove(); // removes current element from list
        bool empty() const;
        operator bool() const { return !empty(); } // checks if empty
};


template<typename T>
 StackDLL<T>::Node::Node(T data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->next = this->prev = NULL; // set next and previous pointers to NULL

}

template<typename T>
 StackDLL<T>::Node::Node(T data, Node* n, Node* p)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->next = n;
    this->prev = p;
}

/*
 * Returns Data at node
 */
template<typename T>
 T StackDLL<T>::Node::getData()
{
    return this->data;
}

/*
 * returns next pointer of a given node
 */
template<typename T>
typename StackDLL<T>::Node* StackDLL<T>::Node::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}

/*
 * returns previous pointer of a given node
 */
template<typename T>
typename StackDLL<T>::Node* StackDLL<T>::Node::getPrev()
{
    return this->prev;
}

/*
 * Sets data of a node
 */
template<typename T>
 void StackDLL<T>::Node::setData(T data)
{
    this->data = data;
}

/*
 * adds a new node holding data to the DLL
 */
template<typename T>
 void StackDLL<T>::add(T data)
{
    // create new node and make it tail
    Node* node = new Node(data);


    // If list is empty, both head/tail point to new element
    if ( this->empty() ) {
        this->head = node;
        this->tail = node;
        node->prev = NULL; // update previous to null
    }

    else {
        node->prev = tail; // if not empty, previous = tail
    }

    this->tail = node; // update DLL tail pointer
    this->size++; // increment size
}


/*
 * removes node from DLL
 */
template<typename T>
 void StackDLL<T>::remove()
{
    if (! empty() ) {
        tail = tail->prev; // previous element becomes new tail
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
}

/*
 * checks if DLL is empty
 */
template<typename T>
 bool StackDLL<T>::empty() const
{
    return ( !head || !tail );
}

} // namespace std


#endif /* STACKDLL_H_ */
```

And here is the actual compiler error:

```
21:12:17 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project project5 ****
make all 
Building target: project5
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "project5"  ./DLLdriver.o ./StackDLL.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [project5] Error 1

21:12:17 Build Finished (took 61ms)
```

Comment: Which symbols aren't found? (Side note - that `operator bool()` should probably be `explicit`, unless you want to allow things like adding a `StackDLL` and an `int`.)

Comment: And seriously, don't put things in `namespace std`.

Comment: @T.C.   Edited to include the compiler error. And regarding the namespace std thing, yes I know it is bad form, but my professor told us to do it, and since I am not doing any serious development in C++ I have yet to stop.

Comment: Well, do you have a `main()` function (in the global namespace)? Because that's what the message says is missing. And your professor told you to put things in the std namespace??!! I can understand telling you to write `using namespace std;`, which is usually considered bad form, but legal; actually adding things to `std` is undefined behavior plain and simple. He needs to be pointed to § 17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std] of the C++ standard.

Comment: I do have a main function, and it is in a separate DLLdriver.cpp function. It is very simple, and not the cause of any of these errors. Maybe the way I am calling it is wrong? At the top of the file have the following.... `#include <iostream>`, `#include "StackDLL.h"` and have an `int main(void) {...}` function nested within the same `namespace std { .....}`

Comment: `main()` must be in the global namespace, not in `namespace std`. I'm starting to suspect that your professor actually meant for you to write `using namespace std;` and not put everything in the `std` namespace.